# get text box values open in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a code, for opening 10 links that I am entering in the text box to open in a new window for each 10 links entered in the text box. But somehow its now working. Could anyone help me in executing it correctly. Below is the code:

```
<html>
<script>
function getValue(v)
{
    var txt_arr=v.split('\n');
    for(var i=0;i<txt_arr.length;i++)
    {
        window.open(txt_arr[i],"_blank");
    }
    //var link=document.getElementById("textLink").value;
    //window.open(link,"_blank");
}
</script>
<body>
<h1>Get Text box value</h1>
<form>
<textarea id="textLink" type="text" name="link_val" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
<button id="btnClick" onClick="getValue(link_val.value)">Open the links</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`link_val.value` is not going to work, cause it does not refer to the element. Sure the variable name matches the name of the textarea, but that's not the same thing.

You need to actually get the element instead, so I would suggest doing that inside the handler:

```
onClick="getValue('link_val')"



function getValue(link_input_name)
{
    var link_input = document.getElementsByName(link_input_name)[0];
    var txt_arr = link_input.value.split('\n');
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your button type is not defined,

by default it's "submit" and it will refresh the page, what you want is a button that does nothing else than the onClick action you need, so put `type="button"` in your button HTML and it will work.

You need to check if your browser don't block popups too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var  a = document.getElementById('textLink');
 function getValue() {
  
    var myWindow = window.open('', "_self");
    //get value in new window use =>window.open('', "_blank");
    myWindow.document.write(a.value);
}
```

```html
<h1>Get Text box value</h1>
<form>
<textarea id="textLink" type="text" name="link_val" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
<button id="btnClick" onClick="getValue()">Open the links</button>
</form>
```